# What is alternative of ".PageMode.IsExperienceEditor" property in JSS-react?

Tags: sitecore-api, jss

What is alternative of `.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor` property of `Sitecore.Context` in JSS-react to verify the ExperienceEditor context ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be `isExperienceEditorActive` defined in `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss`.

Usage:

```
import { isExperienceEditorActive } from "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss";

if (isExperienceEditorActive()) {
  // Do something special in the Experience Editor
}
```

This file also contains other very useful functions.

Credits to Corey Smith and Kam Figy who told me about this.

Comment: The `isExperienceEditorActive()` function was removed somewhere in 2021. It was replaced by the `isEditorActive()` function.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the built-in helper method, the `pageState` (`normal`, `preview`, `editing`) and `pageEditing` (boolean) properties are also available in the layout service context, which there are [samples of](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/0292a05077c4ef21b668eb9c30412f57620c3779/samples/react/src/components/Styleguide-SitecoreContext/index.js#L18) in each JSS sample app:

[image: screenshot]